# How to instantiate an inner class in Enum?

Tags: java, enums

I am wondering how to instantiate an inner class in enum...if i have a code something like this:

```
public enum TestEnum {
    BIG(1),SMALL(2),LARGE(3);
    int i;

    private TestEnum(int i){
        this.i = i;
    }

    public class cs{
        cs c = new cs(){
            public void met(){
                System.out.println("met in enum inner class");
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //instantiate an object of cs here
    }
}
```

Is it possible to instantiate?

Comment: How would you instantiate such inner class if it was not in enum but in simple class? It is the same principle in case of enum.

Comment: What did the compiler tell you?

Answer (score 1):

Since the inner class of the `enum` is non-static, you need an object reference to create new instances of cs:

```
TestEnum.cs sample = TestEnum.BIG.new cs();
//                            ^^^
// This could be any instance of TestEnum
```

Note that you could make `cs` a `static` nested class if `cs` does not use its "owner" `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of the outer class (enum) in order to create the inner.

[tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

```
  TestEnum big = TestEnum.BIG;
        big.new cs();
```

Comment: Please add some more information explaining how your answer resolves the question.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
TestEnum.BIG.new cs();
```